# Selection.Replace ("." for "-") applied to "dd.mm.yyyy" returns "mm-dd-yyyy"

Tags: excel, replace, vba

First time asking something in a Forum, so be patient :D.

While using a macro, I need to change a Whole Columns date from a file coming from SAP.  The date comes in General format as "dd.mm.yyyy".  I need to replace "." for "-" and also apply the date format "dd-MM-yyyy".  Im using this code:

```
range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The method returns the date as "mm-dd-yyyy". As I said, I need "dd-mm-yyyy".  Anyone knows how to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        ary = Split(t, ".")
        r.Clear
        r.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        r.Value = DateSerial(ary(2), ary(1), ary(0))
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer Gary.  Just found an answer and it worked perfectly. I´ll leave you with the code:

Select the cells you wish to convert and run the following:

```
With Selection 
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _ 
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _ 
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _ 
        :=Array(1, 4) 
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy" 
End With
```

Cheers!